# html td no se alinea a la derecha

Tags: html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me podría ayudar a como mover donde dice commercial invoice a la derecha de la pagina, necesito que este lo mas pegado a la derecha.

He intentado con left, right, position y nada mueve el td de ahí.

```html
<table width="100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3"><img src="${logourl}" style="margin: 5px; width: 90; height: 60px;" /></td>
      <td align="right" style="color: #041c64;"><b><h2> COMMERCIAL INVOICE </h2></b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" style="width: 700px"><b>cliente: </b></td>
      <td align="left">cliente</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" style="width: 700px"><b>usd: </b></td>
      <td align="left">USD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #041c64; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"></tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Prueba a añadirle un `rowspan="3"` en el `td` que tiene el texto Commercial invoice y añádele `text-align: right;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si le pones al td donde esta el texto Comercial Invoice el atributo colspan="2" funciona. Sería para que ocupe las 2 columnas que hay y así se pueda alinear a la derecha del todo

Comment: gracias! funcionó perfecto!

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que usas un `rowspan` de 3 filas, pero la primera fila, además del `rowspan` solo tiene una celda adicional, mientras que las restantes tienen 2, por lo que se queda más a la izquierda.

Agregué un `<td></td>` dentro del primer `<tr></tr>` para hacer la misma cantidad que las otras filas. Adicional le puse un `border-collapse` solo para observar el comportamiento, pero se lo puedes quitar:

```html
    <table border="1px" style="border-collapse:collapse">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"><img src="${logourl}" style="margin: 5px; width: 90; height: 60px;"/></td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right" style="color: #041c64;"><b><h2> COMMERCIAL INVOICE </h2></b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td  align="right" style="width: 700px"><b>cliente: </b></td>
        <td  align="left">cliente</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td  align="right" style="width: 700px"><b>usd: </b></td>
        <td  align="left">USD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-bottom: 1px solid #041c64; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"></tr>
        
    </tbody>
    </table>
```